# Compressed video:How to show B and P frames

Tags: video-processing

I want to analyze a compressed video (h264).
I'm encoding using this command:

```
ffmpeg -i in_path -vf scale=340:256,setsar=1:1 -q:v 1 -c:v h264 -f 
rawvideo out_path
```

now I want to see how the P&B frames look like, so I'm using this command in order extract only the b frames:

```
 ffmpeg -ss 0 -i in_vid -t 2 -q:v 2 -vf 
 select="eq(pict_type\,PICT_TYPE_B)" -vsync 0 frameb%03d.jpg
```

The extraction went well, no errors, and the number of frames extracted makes since by theory.
But, I Don't know how to "show" the image, when I'm doing:

```
eog frameb001.jpg
```

I'm getting a normal picture and not what I expected from a B frame, now I understand why doing "eog" won't be good, but I have no idea how to "show" the frame so that it will be meaningful (saw some articles that use HSV to show the frame).

One more thing the fact that I got a meaningful image from the B frames, maybe the extraction wasn't good.

Any help will be great, Thanks a lot!

Comment: _"not what I expected from a B frame"_ well what do you expect to see? _"saw some articles that use HSV to show the frame"_ share a link, maybe then we'll understand what you're trying to do. If you're just trying to detect what's different from the key frame just use a "difference" blend mode (`frame 1=key` vs `frame 2=P/B frame`).

Comment: well B frames are "motion frames", the way there are calculated it is not possible for them to look like a normal frame.

I want to separate a compressed video into his frames,
Let's say I a video "myvid.mp4", I want to take each different frame (means:I,B,P) and do different things with that frame.
Thanks.